# New (and very confused) python user. I can't find how to open the command line

Tags: python-3.x

Hi my only prior programming expreiance is on Matlab so this is the first time I'm learning a "real" programming language.

I've installed python 3.5 and I'm told that it comes pre-loaded with pip, and a command line but I can't for the life of me get it to do anything.  I can open the shell and I can create variables but that's about it.  I can't even find the directory I'm in nor how to set the working directory.  Everytime I try to enter a command I get a syntax error.

How can I access the command line?

Comment: What OS are you on: PC/mac/Linux?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: inspectorG4dget I'm using a PC running windows 10.

Comment: Ok so I've been doing some research and apparently python doesn't recognize the windows space which causes problems when running a script.  I'm trying to run pip but all that happens is that a window opens and then closes instantaneously.  The error message in the window is:           Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '“‘

Comment: Are you opening python.exe or cmd? python.exe is the python command line interpreter, when you're in interpreter mode, you can't access the command line directly. You need to import `os` and use `os.system()`. Also, to call python from command line, open cmd and use `py [arguments]` assuming you installed the integration with windows.

Comment: I think this will help what you're intending (accessing from cmd). It's better to just learn python on the interpreter first though before trying to tinker with python itself. https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html